# How to disable the category url from menu?

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to know if there's any way to hide/remove/disable the category url page from menu.

For example, there's a category named "Clothing" and the subcategories are "T-shirt", "Pants" and "Skirt".

It will show on the front-end menu like this:

Clothing

- T-shirt
- Pants
- Skirt

It shows all products when clicking "Clothing", but I wanna disable it - maybe remove the url from menu or something like that?

Is there any way to make the category visible but remove the link url from menu?
(For example: Don't go to any product page when clicking "Clothing")

※ Magento version: 1.9.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is default Magento functionality 
You could try writing custom jQuery and replace the top category links with javascript:void(0) or use third party extension  like 
https://www.magestore.com/magento-mega-menu-extension.html which allows to setup customer URL or keep it blank for top category

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I write jQuery to replace the top-nav link and it works fine now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the via admin of your site `catalog->manage-categories`. Select the category you wish to hide and under the general information tab you can set to **NO** for option
`Include in Navigation Menu`

Comment: I try it, but it will hide all the category in the Menu. Sorry, maybe I didn't say it clearly. I wanna keep the category but remove the link url from menu.

Comment: I did not Understood  what do you mean , Do you want the menu visible for user ?

Comment: Yes, I wanna make the Menu visible but not go to any product page except for subcategories. Is there any way to make it?

Comment: set that category for static block only

Comment: It'll show empty content if set the category to static block only...Orz

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, If you want to a bit more explained answer for these settings,
you can go through below link.

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/hide-category-from-menu-in-magento-2/

It will give you good understanding of what configuration should be used for different settings.

Check this link too!
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Remove-links-to-top-categories-in-menu/td-p/77072

Comment: Hi, my magento version is 1.9x, so there's maybe some  different from magento 2.x. But anyway, thank you for your reply.